# Slim framework: Linking to pages with html anchor

Tags: php, slim

this link is routed internally to template "pagename.php":

```
<a href="../pagename">Pagename</a>
```

But how can i change the link to anchor "something" on the same page?

It should look like this but it hasn't any effect:

```
<a href="../pagename#something">Pagename</a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `<a href="../pagename.php#something">Pagename</a>`?

Comment: Yes but this isn't a) a semantic url anymore and b) links directly to the page without beeing proceed by the route in index.php

Comment: @WeekendCoder So is your question still valid?

Comment: Appending the `#something` after the route name in the link works just fine for me. Could you show us the rest of your related code?